# Replace using Regex in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to replace every occurrence between

`<fb:like href=` and  `</fb:like>` in notepad++.

I know I can do this with Regex, but i tried for a couple of hours in vain. I have to do this in a large SQL export file.

How can I do this?

Comment: search for `(?<=fb:like\shref=).*?(?=</fb:like>)` - replace with whatever you want

Comment: Add this as answer, I can accept it @nixda

Answer (score 0):

Test string
`<fb:like href=https://regexr.com/46rin>Tag text</fb:like>`

Option A)

`(?:<fb:like\shref=)(.*?)(?:</fb:like>)` yields `https://regexr.com/46rin>Tag text`

Option B)

`(?:<fb:like\shref=.*>)(.*)(?:</fb:like>)` yields `Tag text`

It is not clear to me which one you want exactly.

Comment: @nixda gives the right answer in comment, yours doesn't explain how you do the replace.

Comment: @Toto If his answer is right then so is mine. If mine doesn't explain replace, his doesn't either, so be coherent.

Comment: @nixda answer and yours are completly different, we can use it for replacing, we can't do such with yours or explain how you do.

Comment: Hahaha sure man. He explains everything in that one line comment. You know what, you are right and I'm wrong. Enjoy your life.